# Fill in Data automatically in Django

Tags: python, database, django, models, fill

In my django project i have a models.py. In this models.py I have the following class:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    house_number = models.IntegerField()
    zip = models.IntegerField() # PLZ
    place = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank)
```

I don't want to fill in this data in the admin site on my website.
Is there a possibility, to fill in this datas automatically in Django or Python?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What source would you like load the data to be filled from? Other datebase, text file, ...? But yes, it is possible to fill them in using python+django

Comment: Yes, i want to fill it from a text file

Comment: Look at fixtures, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/, create the file json/xml once and load it.

Answer (score 0):

Example model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

How to add data:

```
from mysite.blog.models import Blog
b = Blog(name='Beatles Blog', tagline='All the latest Beatles news.')
b.save()
```

For more details on how to add data:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects

In python loop over a textfile and parse the data as you want. Then use the above line once per "row" to add a new database entry.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question..
But thank's for your answer